# How to initialize a static field as an object of the same class in Java?

Tags: java

I have a simple nested class A. (In C I would use a struct.) I want to provide a default object A.DEFAULT of class A without having to call the constructor each time. So my idea was this:

```
class MyApplication {
   class A {
        int x;
        double y;
        public static final A DEFAULT = new A(0, 0.0);

        public A(int x, double y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
    …
```

Obviously, this does not work, because the constructor cannot be called before the class has been loaded.

**How to handle this?**
How does e. g. java.awt.Color.RED handle this?

Comment: `public static final DEFAULT = new A(0, 0.0);` this will not even compile... and what is `Color.RED`?

Comment: Do you insist declaring `A` as nested class? Because I would suggest not to nest the class at all. Unless there is a strong relation between the nested class and its outer class, which I think there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obvious problem that you missed a type (`A`) on the definition of `DEFAULT`...

The problem isn't that "the class has [not] been loaded". The problem is that, in Java, every instance of an inner class implicitly has a reference to the instance of the outer class that created it. Since there is no instance of the outer class when initializing the `static` field, you get an error:

```
MyApplication.java:5: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        public static final A DEFAULT = new A(0, 0.0);
                                        ^
```

And in all but the most recent Java versions, even declaring a `static` field inside a non-static inner class is illegal, no matter what value you give it:

```
MyApplication.java:5: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class MyApplication.A
        public static final A DEFAULT = new A(0, 0.0);
                              ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
```

The solution is to make the inner class *not* have a reference to the outer class, which you do by declaring `A` as static:

```
class MyApplication {
    static class A {
    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is no longer true with recent java versions. [JEP 395](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395): "Relax the longstanding restriction whereby an inner class cannot declare a member that is explicitly or implicitly static."

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That sounds like a different restriction though?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Edited.

Comment: Feel free to edit and improve :)

Comment: Thank you. After 2 years of not using Java, I had overlooked the difference between inner classes and nested classes.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with constructor calls, you've just made a couple of simple mistakes.

You haven't specified a type for `DEFAULT`:

```
public static final A DEFAULT
```

You cannot instantiate an `A` without an instance of `MyApplication`, as `A` is an inner class:

```
new MyApplication().new A(0, 0.0);
```

However you probably didn't intend to make `A` an inner class, so I would mark it as `static`. Without any extra context, it seems as if `A` has no relation to `MyApplication` so shouldn't depend on it.

---

*Note: In Java 15 and below, static declarations weren't even allowed in inner classes (as pointed out by [@Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577290/how-to-initialize-a-static-field-as-an-object-of-the-same-class-in-java/70577365#comment124761775_70577350)).*